# Create the aggregate if not exists

Tags: postgresql

in my sql script I want to return with the last query some records. For that query I'm using a aggregate:

```
CREATE AGGREGATE array_agg_mult(anyarray) (
    SFUNC = array_cat,
    STYPE = anyarray,
    INITCOND = '{}'
);
```

So if I call the script twice I have to drop the aggregate at the end. But the script should end with a custom sql query. Is there a way to say something like `CREATE  OR REPLACE`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could simply `DROP AGGREGATE IF EXISTS array_agg_mult(anyarray);` prior to your `CREATE AGGREGATE`

Note that this may throw an error if you change the parameters/signature, so you'd need to adjust for that if you do.

Manual Reference:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-dropaggregate.html

Answer (score 5):

```
DO $$ BEGIN
CREATE AGGREGATE array_agg_mult(anyarray) (
    SFUNC = array_cat,
    STYPE = anyarray,
    INITCOND = '{}'
);
EXCEPTION
    WHEN duplicate_function THEN NULL;
END $$;
```

seems to work as well.